# Selenium ChromeOptions Prefs Default OpenFileDialog Directory

Tags: selenium, chrome-options

I can use:

```
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadDirectory);
```

to set the default download directory, but I can't seem to figure out what the prefs key is for setting the default open file directory.

I tried looking for a list of all the possible preference keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example to automatically download a PDF with chrome :

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", "c:\\Download");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.plugins_disabled", new []{"Chrome PDF Viewer"});

var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

Comment: I am not trying to set the download directory; I am trying to set the OpenFileDialog directory.

Comment: You got me intrigued, what would be the purpose to use the Open dialogue with Selenium since the page/file is loaded with driver.get() ?

Comment: I ended up just setting the directory once the dialog is open using    SendKeys.SendWait(pathName); and then SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");

Comment: I am still trying to find a list of all possible preference keys.

Comment: For the default prefs: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences

Comment: The default folder for the open dialogue is most probably handled by Windows and stored in the registry.